# 'setNewsstandIconImage' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift2, newsstand-kit, xcode7.1

I see the strange compile error:

> 'setNewsstandIconImage' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer

But this method was available in ios 7 and 8 on Xcode 6.4. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack how to do this in Swift 2.2:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().performSelector(Selector("setNewsstandIconImage:"), withObject: image)
```

And you will have warning instead compile error.